# Getting bad accuracy of classification using Keras VGG-16

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I am very new to the data science domain and directly jumped to TensorFlow models. I've worked on examples provided on the website before. My first time doing any project using it.

I am building an image classifier using Kerns, Tensorflow. I have a dataset of 4 different vegetables (Bell Pepper, Chile Pepper, New Mexico Green Chile, Tomato) each including five subfolders (damaged, dried, old, ripe, unripe) except the Tomato dried class because there are no images provided in the dataset.

Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow import data
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from pathlib import Path
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
data_dir = Path('drive/My Drive/VegNet_wo_subclasses')

# Check how many files are included in origin dataset
img_amount = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg'))) # '*/*.jpg' indicates all included subfolder images
sub_amount = len(list(data_dir.glob('*'))) # '*' indicates all included subfolders
print('Found {} images in {} subfolders'.format(img_amount, sub_amount))

# Image size recommendation
# https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_Image_resolution_should_I_use_for_training_for_deep_neural_network
IMAGE_SIZE = (256, 256)

BATCH_SIZE = 16

VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2

SEED = 404

# Split into datasets
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    labels = 'inferred',
    label_mode = 'categorical',
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = SEED,
    validation_split = VALIDATION_SPLIT,
    subset = 'training'
)

class_amount = len(train_ds.class_names)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    labels = 'inferred',
    label_mode = 'categorical',
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = SEED,
    validation_split = VALIDATION_SPLIT,
    subset = 'validation'
)

# Prefetching samples in GPU memory helps maximize GPU utilization.
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Build model
vgg = keras.applications.VGG16(
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
    include_top=False,
)

vgg.trainable = False

def build_model():

    # create an input mode
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(256, 256, 3), name="Input")
    
    # add a Flatten or a GlobalAveragePooling layer
    x = layers.Flatten()(vgg.output)

    # add a Dense layer
    x = layers.Dense(19, activation='relu')(x)

    # add a Dropout layer
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2, input_shape = (2,))(x)

    # add the final layer
    outputs = layers.Dense(19)(x)
    
    # build the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs=vgg.input, outputs=outputs)

    # compile the model
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics='accuracy')
    # print the summary
    model.summary()

    return model

model = build_model()

# train the model
history = model.fit(train_ds, 
                    epochs = 20, 
                    validation_data=val_ds,
                    verbose = 1)
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 256, 256, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 256, 256, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 64)      0         
                                                                 
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 128, 128)     73856     
                                                                 
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 128, 128)     147584    
                                                                 
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 64, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 64, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 64, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 256)       0         
                                                                 
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 32, 512)       1180160   
                                                                 
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 32, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 32, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 16, 16, 512)       0         
                                                                 
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 32768)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 19)                622611    
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 19)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 19)                380       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 15,337,679
Trainable params: 622,991
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/20
309/309 [==============================] - 338s 953ms/step - loss: 0.6579 - accuracy: 0.1976 - val_loss: 0.5727 - val_accuracy: 0.2006
Epoch 2/20
309/309 [==============================] - 6s 20ms/step - loss: 0.5253 - accuracy: 0.1994 - val_loss: 0.4805 - val_accuracy: 0.2006
Epoch 3/20
309/309 [==============================] - 6s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4441 - accuracy: 0.1994 - val_loss: 0.4108 - val_accuracy: 0.2006
Epoch 4/20
309/309 [==============================] - 6s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3834 - accuracy: 0.1994 - val_loss: 0.3582 - val_accuracy: 0.2006
Epoch 5/20
309/309 [==============================] - 6s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3375 - accuracy: 0.1994 - val_loss: 0.3184 - val_accuracy: 0.2006
Epoch 6/20
309/309 [==============================] - 6s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3027 - accuracy: 0.1994 - val_loss: 0.2882 - val_accuracy: 0.2006
Epoch 7/20
309/309 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2762 - accuracy: 0.1994
```

I moved all my subclasses onto one folder layer by hand (Bell_Pepper_Damaged, Bell_Pepper_Dried, etc.) - my dataset now includes a total of 19 folders (4 vegetables * 5 expressions - 1 expression (Tomato_Dried)).

I want to build my own model on top of the existing VGG16 Model (`def build_model()`).

Currently I am facing several problems and have several questions:

1. My subfolders are heavily unbalanced (lowest amount of images: 27, highest amount of images: 1234). Kicking out minority classes or implementing data augmentation to create different versions of those images and filling up my minority classes. What do you recommend?
2. I am not sure if I create my own model in a correct way. What can I do to improve it?
3. If I train my model it only achieves an accuracy of 0.1994 (see output below) - what can I do to improve it?

Comment: I think you need to explode the subfolders. Instead of 4 *5 - 1 into `19` (single level), but I am not sure. As for debugging, what happen when you truncate your dataset i.e. make every category `27` images (`27*19 = 513` photos) does the model still underfit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think image_dataset_from_directory deals with directories and subdirectories recursively.

I'm not sure how real-world this intended to be but more typically you would already know which vegetable it is and you want to classify within that. So you would build one model per vegetable.